# how to change android progress bar thickness

Tags: android, android-styles, android-progressbar

this should be a very easy to customize style...

i want a horizontal progress bar that is slithly thick (or that i can customize the thickness) and the color matches the apps color

if i do

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textLoading"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
     />
```

the progress bar is horizontal and matches app visual identity... but is too thin... the person need glases to see it

if i do

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textLoading"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
         />
```

the progress bar is good thickness but the color is a stupid yellow that matches nothing in this plannet

how can i customize individual parameters???

Answer (score 12):

there are many ways to achieve what you need:

1- use `android:scaleY="8"` in your XML file

or from code

mProgressBar.setScaleY(3f);

2- `style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"`
this will make you have Horizontal progress bar, so you can inherit it in styles and edit it as follows:

```
<style name="CustomProgressBarHorizontal" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
      <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_progress_bar_horizontal</item>
      <item name="android:minHeight">10dp</item>
      <item name="android:maxHeight">20dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example for a progress bar:

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/my_progressbar" />
```

and here is my_progressbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
        <size android:height="20dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal">
    <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:radius="10dp"
                />
            <size android:height="20dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/yellow"/>
        </shape>
    </scale>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Here is an example of how it looks:
[image: thick progressbar]

Answer (score 7):

You can use **Android Material Progress Bar**:
`com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator`

XML example:

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progress="45"
    app:indicatorColor="@color/blue_light"
    app:trackColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:trackCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:trackThickness="10dp" />
```

Now you can use `app:trackThickness` to adjust the thickness of the progress bar

You can also check out Google's Material Design page regarding Material Progress Bar here: https://material.io/components/progress-indicators/android#using-progress-indicators

Comment: For circular progress bar with same functionalities replace ``<ProgressBar />`` with ``<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator />``

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the style with:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    style="@style/CustomProgressBar"
```

with:

```
<style name="CustomProgressBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
      <item name="minHeight">32dip</item>  <!-- default 16dp -->
      <item name="maxHeight">32dip</item>  <!-- default 16dp -->
</style>
```

If you want to customize the color use:

```
<ProgressBar
    style="@style/CustomProgressBar"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:theme="@style/CustomProgressBarTheme"
    />
```

with:

```
  <style name="CustomProgressBarTheme">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/....</item>
  </style>
```

[image]